# How to re-obtain ssh access to remote server

Tags: linux, ssh, security

I was working on my website using Linux Terminal on VirtualBox and was able to secure access to the remote server without password authentication. All I needed to type was "ssh {sudo user}@{IP}". After the pipeline broke, I lost the ability to re-connect.

Thinking it was a firewall related issue, I retraced my steps (which was easy since I am following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=goToXTC96Co&t=318s). Doing that, I saw that
I had allowed ssh access before enabling it, so I don't think the firewall is causing it.

After thinking it was a key-related issue, I generated a new key pair, (overwriting the old pair by accident), and tried secure copying the generated public key to the server, which was unable to work. By overwriting the private key for the public key on my server, I may have screwed myself, but being new at this, there could be other solutions I don't know of. T**his is the output I am getting now (with debug info):**

```
root@john-VirtualBox:/home/john# ssh jw@xxx.xxx.xx.xxx -v


OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017 

 - debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
 - debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
 - debug1: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xx.xxx [xxx.xxx.xx.xxx] port 22.
 - debug1: Connection established.
 - debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
 - debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
 - debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
 - debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
 - debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
 - debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
 - debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
 - debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
 - debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
 - debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
 - debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
 - debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
 - debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
 - debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
 - debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
 - debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
 - debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
 - debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version
   OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
 - debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH* compat
   0x04000000
 - debug1: Authenticating to xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:22 as 'jw'
 - debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
 - debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
 - debug1: kex: host key
 - algorithm: rsa-sha2-512
 - debug1: kex: server->client cipher:chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC
   <implicit> compression: none
 - debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
   MAC: <implicit> compression: none
 - debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
 - debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 - debug1: Host 'xxx.xxx.xx.xxx' is known and matches the RSA host key.
 - debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:4
 - debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
 - debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
 - debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks 
 - debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
 - debug1:
   kex_input_ext_info:server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
 - debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
 - debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
 - debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
 - debug1: Offering public key: RSA   
   SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx /root/.ssh/id_rsa
 - debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
 - debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
 - debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
 - debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
 - debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
```

**Here is the error output I receive (without debug info):**

```
jw@xxx.xxx.xx.xxx: Permission denied (publickey)
```

**/etc/ssh/sshd_config changed settings prior to issue:**

- PermitRootLogin no (to prevent hackers from obtaining root access)
- PasswordAuthentication no (to allow me to ssh without having to type
  in password everytime)

Comment: Hi and Welcome to Super User. It's good that you posted a link to the tutorial for context. In addition to the link, it would help us answer your question if you edited the question to add a step by step list of what you actually did and what results you got. This way, you save the people trying to help you time and if the problem is that you made a mistake following the instructions, it will become apparent.

Comment: I ended up having the problem resolved by the host company! They just set PermitRootLogin and PasswordAuthentication to "yes", where I had them set to "no". I appreciate your comment and I will make to elaborate better in my future posts.

Comment: @timotree not necessarily step by step, not like baby steps, but generally speaking, showing the commands run.  Though he did show ssh -v,  that's `-v` for verbose so it shows info to help. The other thing that is useful is server side log.   It is a good idea for anybody to note down all commands run, so when one has a question they can give that.  In this case,of ssh, it is often not that relevant, and the info he provided is ok.. Generally when troubleshooting ssh, people don't tend to ask what commands were run before the ssh command.

Comment: @timotree so troubleshooting ssh , a person havnig the problem would generally say what is going wrong and eg what ssh -v or -vvv says, (and sshd server log), and then they'd ask them to try certain things to see what they can and can't do, and to verify if things are set up correctly,  and they'd suggest some possible solutions.  Also bear in mind that a person might try hundreds of commands many of them irrelevant, and so listing all of them may make the question irrelevant to people so people shouldn't even just blindly list all commands either.